# Function of the 'double' leaf on a pomelo tree

Tags: plant-anatomy, trees

What is the function of the 'double leaf' (I'm unsure what the technical name is...) on a pomelo tree leaf?

Furthermore, what evolutionary 'problem' is this structure solving?

See image with arrows that indicate the two parts to the leaf.

[image]

Comment: It's a lobed stem, i.e. the stem of the leaf has lobed mini leaves. It looks like the leaf originally was like this, and the stem developed lobes: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/Wild_Orange_underside_of_leaves_%2810868374834%29.jpg/1280px-Wild_Orange_underside_of_leaves_%2810868374834%29.jpg